# ionic cordova run android is giving gradle error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle

When I hit ionic cordova run android the following is happening:

```
D:\Leraning\myApp>ionic cordova build android
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected

Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Leraning\myApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\Leraning\myApp

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\nagasatya.mandalapu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 1 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
```

[image]

I have gradle installed and I tried by killing and restarting, but seems the same error.

**update**

```
D:\Leraning\myApp\platforms\android>gradle clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > Connect to repo.jfrog.org:443 [repo.jfrog.org/34.233.3.28, repo.jfrog.org/52.86.234.14] failed: Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s

D:\Leraning\myApp\platforms\android>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error. Try cleaning the gradle and try to build the application again just in case.

Comment: i tried with running gradle clean command..it gives 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'clean' not found in root project 'myApp'.

Comment: go to ./platforms/android/ and run ./gradlew clean

Comment: i don't understand why this is happening.....its happening for every project

Comment: let me try karthik

Comment: updated my question whith what i get when  i run gradle clean

Comment: can you post your gradle?

Comment: I didn't get u Karthik ....can u tell me how to do that

Comment: you have build.gradle file right? Can you post it?

Comment: its not allowing me t poast that code

Comment: I have added an answer please check it and let me know if that is working.

Answer (score 0):

In the below part of the code from build.gradle

```
repositories {
   jcenter()
     maven {
       url 'https://maven.google.com'
     }
}
```

Replace

```
maven {
url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```

with

```
google()
```

Final part would be

```
repositories {
   jcenter()
   google()
}
```

Comment: let me try and get back to u